# Unable to set the font for my cells in UItableviewcell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, fonts

I have a UITableViewCell that have a Label contained within the cell. The problem is that i wish to change the font to "Century Gothic" however when I set the label to "Century Gothic" using the storyboard this does not work.
The font seems to be stuck on the default "Avenir" font. I set label to Attributed in the label settings in order to select the font"Century Gothic" from the drop down menu.

I have tried to set it in code however this does not seem to work either.
when I set the font to "Avenir" in code it will allow me to adjust the size of the font. However when I set the font to "Century Gothic" in code it will not produce the "Century Gothic" or let me adjust the size of the font.

I have tried both adjusting the font using storyboard settings and code.

```
//setting up tableview rows
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return foodTitleArray.count
}


//what cell is & how it looks
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = Tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell123") as! UITableViewCell1

    //How text looks in tableview sections
    cell.foodTitle.font = UIFont(name: "Century Gothic", size:58)
    cell.foodTitle.textColor = UIColor.white
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 211/255, green: 211/255, blue: 211/255, alpha: 1)


    return (cell)
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you added your font into "font provided by application" in the info.plist?

Comment: You're dequeueing a UITableViewCell, but trying to set the `foodTitle` so it seems like you're trying to use a custom cell. Maybe try setting the cell class in storyboard and set the correct type when you dequeue it in code?

Comment: Potential issue: `UIFont(name: "Century Gothic", size:58)`, `Century Gothic` isn't the postscript name of the font. Potential issue: you are mixing `.text` and `.attributedText`. What is `foodTitle` in a `UITableViewCell`. In a custom one maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You are casting the cell as a UITableView cell when you dequeue it, so it doesn't have a `foodTitle` label.

You need to cast it as your custom cell type, then you will be able to access your fields.

Better still register is as the correct cell type in viewDidLoad...

```
tableView. register(MyCustomCellClass.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCellID")
```

and then you can use the newer API for dequeueing it

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCellID", for: indexPath)
```

and there is no need to cast it at all.

If you want to be really smart, add a static property to the customer cell and use that for the cell ID:

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
   static let cellID = "cellIDString" //can be anything as it's never seen
   // all the existing code...
}
```

and then use it as

```
MyCustomCell.cellID
```

whenever the cell identifier is needed.  This gets rid of the string literals, helps readability, and removed typo errors.

Comment: Ah, you've added the info re storyboards.  In that case the registering the cell is not needed, but the rest still applies.

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/tadija/cb4ec0cbf0a89886d488d1d8b595d0e9 may help you. It has all fonts' names that can be used in `UIFont(name: ,size: )`